# I was wondering if you could tell me about the difference between imread and cvLoadImageM

Tags: c++, opencv

Mat img=imread("box.png",1);

Mat img=cvLoadImage("box.png",1);

When i tried the former one, the project couldn't load the file but when i used the latter one, it did. So.. and box.png was in the project folder. Can you help me what is wrong with my imread? or should i add a directory where box.png is located?

what im trying to make is this code pulling out mser regions from the image. And the error occured running the code when compiler couldn't load the image file, and also even if i had changed **imread** to **cvLoadImageM** the code stopped at

> ms(box, regions, Mat());

so am i doing something wrong????????here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
//#include <string.h>
#include "opencv\cv.h"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main()
{
    Mat box = imread("01a.png",1);
    if(box.empty()) 
    { 
        fprintf(stderr, "Can not load image" ); 
        return -1; 
    } 
    MSER ms;
    vector<vector<Point>> regions;
    ms(box, regions, Mat());
    for (int i = 0; i < regions.size(); i++)
    {
        ellipse(box, fitEllipse(regions[i]), Scalar(255));
    }
    imshow("mser", box);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The function imread works fine, I use it all of the time. Are you getting an error, or is something else happening?

Comment: This code to load the image is fine. If the size of your image is large, the MSER feature detection could take a few seconds. Does it ever return? Your code compiles and runs fine on my machine.

Comment: no when i run the code it first goes into if part and stops and, if i make adjustment with cvLoadImageM, and run it again, then it shows me an error message, "0x77C4AA3C(ntdll.dll)에(mser_component_extractor.exe의) exceptional cases.. 0xC0000374: heap was damaged(variable: 0x77C5FE38).(I'm using Korean interface so i don't know how to translate the message into english but if i do..its sort of like above)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem yesterday and I found a solution. Make sure the opencv library used matches your build mode (e.g. Release -> cvcore242.lib (dll) Debug -> cvcore242d.lib (or dll)) for each opencv library. Make sure to change your project deps->linker->dependencies to load the correct (Debug or Release) opencv libraries.

An alternative is to switch your build mode Debug <-> Release but I imagine you want to set up each one of the build modes with the proper opencv libraries, for the long run.

Answer (score 0):

imread() is part of the new OpenCV C++ interface and is used with a Mat structure. cvLoadImage() is a C function that returns a IplImage* (pointer to IplImage)

Comment: yes i know the difference between cvLoadImage and imread.. i was asking about the different thing..;;

Answer (score 0):

like Cricketer said cvLoadImage() returns a pointer to the image.
Change this in your code

```
    - Mat box = imread("01a.png",1);

    + IplImage* pBox = cvLoadImage("01a.png");
    + Mat box = pBox;
```

The code worked fine for me both ways putting in the full path to the image

```
"C:\\Users\\noob\\Pictures\\01a.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

so, imread failed, and you tried to resolve that using cvLoadImage ? bah, no, don't do that.

please go and check, if you're mixing debug  & release code, like *d.libs  linked to release build or the other way. it's most likely related to that